# Order data Preprocessing before Sequential Pattern Mining

Tags: r, sequential

I have 2 questions about Sequential Pattern Mining.

```
df <- data.frame(member_no = c('1','1','1','2','3','4','5','4','3','2','3','1','2','2','4'),
                 year_month = c('2020_Apr','2021_Mar','2021_Mar','2022_Jan','2023_May','2022_Dec','2019_Nov','2022_Feb','2021_Aug','2021_Aug','2020_Jan','2021_Mar','2021_Dec','2021_Jul','2023_Apr'),
                 product = c('A','B','B','B','C','C','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','B','C'))


dataset <- df |> 
  select(member_no, year_month, product) |> 
  group_by(member_no, year_month) |> 
  summarize(itemset = paste(as.character(product), collapse = ','))


write.table(dataset, 'data.txt', sep = ',', quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = F)

transaction <- read_baskets('data.txt', sep = ',', info = c('sequenceID', 'eventID'))
inspect(transaction)

freq.s <- cspade(transaction, parameter = list(support = 0.001), 
                 control = list(verbose = T))
inspect(head(freq.s, 1000, by = 'support'))

df1 <- freq.s

# output all results
df1 <- as(df1, "data.frame") %>% as_tibble()
df1$pattern <- (str_count(df1$sequence, ",") + 1)
df1 <- df1[order(-df1$support),] # descending
```

Q1: `View(dataset)` shows the **member_no 1** has 3 itemsets in one single month.
Do I only count it only once as the sequence **<{A}, {B}>** or **<{A}, {B,B,B}>**

Q2: Why would `sum(df1$support)` more than 1?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Hi @TarJae, 

Thanks for your remind. I have updated my content by adding the full code.
My question is whether I perform the #5 line code 
--> distinct(member_no, category, .keep_all = TRUE)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to construct a minimal reproducible example. It may seem unnecessary, but keep in mind that answering questions requires significant mental effort. Providing a minimal reproducible example helps streamline the process for us and often leads to more efficient problem-solving. Additionally, the process of creating such an example can be highly educational. You may even find that it helps you resolve your issue independently.

Comment: Thanks for instruction! I revise the code and questions again! Please help check it.
Appreciate it very much.

Comment: Any suggestion please??